# Adding contact to group break sync

Tags: android

**Update:**
I discovered that this problem was due to the group not having a source_id (found by looking at the Log.d messages - there were messages from the sync adapter).
I asked a related question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674548/how-do-i-create-a-group-with-a-source-id-reference)

And eventually figured out the cause of that.

**Original Question:**
I am adding a contact to a group using the following code.
When complete I see the contact in the group on the phone, but the sync fails with "Sync is currently experiencing problems.  It wil be back shortly."

If I run this app, it does say the groupmembership is bad.
Any idea's what I am doing wrong?

```
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 132);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,  30);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

**Update:**
The values shown are obviously hard coded, and changed from what I am showing below.

I manually created a group (11 myGroup1) and create another gorup 40 (myNewTestGroup) and 
group membership record 1934 (membership in group 11) seem to work but 1933 (membership in group 40) is broken (causes sync to fail).

Here is what I have looked at between the groupmembership records.
They seem identical other than the expected _id differences.
Any idea's on what I must be missing?  As I said above the app i pointed to does find an issue with the group membership, but I don't see what it is.

```
: --- begin ---
: key =  mimetype , value = vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership
: key =  _id , value = 1934
: key =  data1 , value = 11
: key =  contact_id , value = 294
: key =  data2 , value = null
: key =  data3 , value = null
: key =  lookup , value = 1645i7c8c143a8f6bc41e.2452i1485527796.66ixxxx914
: key =  raw_contact_id , value = 132
: --- end ---

: --- begin ---
: key =  mimetype , value = vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership
: key =  _id , value = 1933
: key =  data1 , value = 40
: key =  contact_id , value = 294
: key =  data2 , value = null
: key =  data3 , value = null
: key =  lookup , value = 1645i7c8c143a8f6bc41e.2452i1485527796.66ixxxx914
: key =  raw_contact_id , value = 132
: --- end ---

And here are the group records

: key =  title , value = myGroup1
: key =  data_set , value = null
: key =  _id , value = 11
: key =  group_visible , value = 1
: key =  system_id , value = null
: key =  should_sync , value = 1
: key =  notes , value = myGroup1
: key =  deleted , value = 0
: --- end ---

: --- begin ---
: key =  title , value = myNewTestGroup
: key =  data_set , value = null
: key =  _id , value = 40
: key =  group_visible , value = 1
: key =  system_id , value = null
: key =  should_sync , value = 1
: key =  notes , value = myNewTestGroup
: key =  deleted , value = 0
: --- end ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this problem was due to the group not having a source_id (found by looking at the Log.d messages - there were messages from the sync adapter). I asked a related question 
 [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674548/how-do-i-create-a-group-with-a-source-id-reference)
and eventually figured out the cause of that as well.