# How do I create a group with a source_id reference?

Tags: android

**Update**

I finally figured this one out:
The key is to create the group with an account name and account type, something that is not really apparent looking at the documentation (there are no fields with those name in ContactsContract.Groups they are in the SyncColumns).  When you create the group with those two values, the sync process will generate the source_id for you,  at which point you can add member using either the group row id or the source_id.

Here is some sample code if anyone needs it.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,"yourGroupName");
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE,"com.google");
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,"someuser@gmail.com");
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE,1);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

then to add members:

```
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 22);
//values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,  56);
// the above or 
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_SOURCE_ID,"sourceIdthatIsFilledInAfterSync");
//context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

**Original question:**
I have been struggling with an issue related to syncing group memberships and think I figured out the cause, but I don't know how to fix it.

After creating 2 groups , one via code the the other manually and then query the groups using these columns.

```
private final static String[] GROUP_COLUMNS = {
    ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
    ContactsContract.Groups.DATA_SET,
    ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES,
    ContactsContract.Groups.SYSTEM_ID,
    ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE,
    ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED,
    ContactsContract.Groups.SHOULD_SYNC,
    ContactsContract.Groups.SOURCE_ID,
    ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE   
};
```

I can dump out the results as this.

```
: --- begin ---
: key =  title , value = myNewTestGroup
: key =  data_set , value = null
: key =  _id , value = 45
: key =  sourceid , value = null
: key =  group_visible , value = 1
: key =  system_id , value = null
: key =  should_sync , value = 1
: key =  notes , value = myNewTestGroup
: key =  deleted , value = 0
: --- end ---

: --- begin ---
: key =  title , value = Mytest2
: key =  data_set , value = null
: key =  _id , value = 46
: key =  sourceid , value = 144c8b8d0cca8a52
: key =  group_visible , value = 1
: key =  system_id , value = null
: key =  should_sync , value = 1
: key =  notes , value = Mytest2
: key =  deleted , value = 0
: --- end ---
```

The manually create group (Mytest2) has a souceid which is listed as a column in ContactsContract.SyncColumns,  while the code generated group has null.

I see references to source_id in may places in the android docs but I can't see how to obtain one.

I think somehow i would get this if i associate the group with an account.
Does anyone know how to associate at group with an account, or otherwise get this source id field set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this one out: The key is to create the group with an account name and account type, something that is not really apparent looking at the documentation (there are no fields with those name in ContactsContract.Groups they are in the SyncColumns). When you create the group with those two values, the sync process will generate the source_id for you, at which point you can add member using either the group row id or the source_id.

Here is some sample code if anyone needs it.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,"yourGroupName");
values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE,"com.google");
values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,"someuser@gmail.com");
values.put(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE,1);
context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

then to add members:

```
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 22);
//values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,  56);
// the above or 
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_SOURCE_ID,"sourceIdthatIsFilledInAfterSync");
context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Answer (score 1):

The data in sourceid still needs to be set in the second example before you are able to retrieve it.

here is what the docs have to say about sourceid:

> String SOURCE_ID read/write:
>
> String that uniquely identifies this row to its source account.
>   Typically it is set at the time the raw contact is inserted and never
>   changed afterwards. The one notable exception is a new raw contact: it
>   will have an account name and type (and possibly a data set), but no
>   source id. This indicates to the sync adapter that a new contact needs
>   to be created server-side and its ID stored in the corresponding
>   SOURCE_ID field on the phone.

Comment: I see how this might help for a raw contact , since I can set an account name and type when creating it, but I don't see those fields for a group.

Comment: possibly some entry in the dataset field when creating the group? Any idea's on how to do that?

Comment: the data set field is null in both the good and bad groups however

Comment: @nPn SyncColumns also provides a "dirty" flag, i suggest raising the flag to see if it then provides you with a sourceid once it has been synchronized (part of .SyncColumns)


`public static final String DIRTY

Flag indicating that VERSION has changed, and this row needs to be synchronized by its owning account.

Constant Value: "dirty"`

Comment: In the end this answer is useful.  The process for a group is similar to that of a raw contact.  If the doc for group has included the Account name and account type fields (like it does for raw contacts), then this would have been easy to figure out